# Android Place Picker: full explanation

Tags: android

I have problems to understand how to use the Place Picker.
First: have I to download the `PlacePicker`?
I not, i try to write this code: `PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();`

IDE show "PlacePicker" red, like it can't resolve it. If I press `ALT + ENTER`, IDE suggest "Insert App indexing API code". I select this, but nothing seems to happens (probably IDE change some other file, but the error is still present).

Probably I have bad knowledge of this tool. So i need explanation about the use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not following the correct guide. You have to first signup and get a key to use the `PlacePicker` API. You can do the same [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup).

After this, add the gradle dependency: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'` to your app level build.gradle file and sync your project.

You'll be able to use the `PlacePicker` API after this, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker).

Answer (score 0):

Now the code compile, but, when executed, the map picker is shown only for few seconds and then disappear. I need to load the picker when a button is pressed.

```
public class Manage_Point extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage__point);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new Pick_coordinates(this));
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}}

public class Pick_coordinates implements View.OnClickListener {
private Activity activity;

public Pick_coordinates(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        activity.startActivityForResult(builder.build(activity), 1);

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```